# return large string data from wcf service in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, wcf, serialization

I have written WCF service methods that return large string data as below:

```
string IEmpService.GetEmployeeInfo()
{
    StringBuilder strData = new StringBuilder();
    //create list of user class  
    List<Users> lstUsers = new List<Users>();
    // populate 10000000 data from DB table at a time
    _ods = populateEmpData();// data store to dataset
    // convert dataset to list
    lstUsers = (from dr in _ods.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                   select new Users
                   {
                       UsersID = dr.Field<int>("UsersID"),
                       UserName = dr.Field<string>("UserName"),
                       Password = dr.Field<string>("Password")
                   }).ToList();

    // do Serialize of above list  and store it to a string builder(this create huge amount of string dada)     
    strData.Append(Utility.DeSerilization.comonMapper.SerializeList<List<Users>>(lstUsers));
    return strData.ToString(); 
}
```

User class:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRootAttribute(ElementName = "Users", IsNullable = false)]
public class Users
{
    [XmlElement("UsersID")]
    public int UsersID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("UserName")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to run the service it throws the following exception:

> strData.ToString()
>   'strData.ToString()' threw an exception of type
>   'System.OutOfMemoryException string {System.OutOfMemoryException}

And when I add service reference and show data to a grid view it also shows error.

What is the right approach to return very big string from WCF service?

Comment: 10000000 records through a service a is too much, think on how these records are used and if the is no better access pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with trying to grab so much data at once is the massive overhead of desearializing all that data. I would break up the data into more manageable chunks on the server side, and make repeated requests to the service for the next chunk, until there are no chunks left.

I also don't know why you are doing the serialization yourself. I would simply create a [data contract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx) to hold your data, and let WCF handle the serialization / deserializeation automatically :)

EDIT:

```
 [DataContract]
 public class Users
 {
     [DataMember]
     public int UsersID { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
     public string UserName { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
     public string Password { get; set; }
 }

 public List<Users> IEmpService.GetEmployeeInfo()
 {
     //create list of user class  
     List<Users> lstUsers = new List<Users>();
     // populate 10000000 data from DB table at a time
     _ods = populateEmpData();// data store to dataset
     // convert dataset to list
     lstUsers = (from dr in _ods.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
               select new Users
               {
                   UsersID = dr.Field<int>("UsersID"),
                   UserName = dr.Field<string>("UserName"),
                   Password = dr.Field<string>("Password")
               }).ToList();

     return lstUsers;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.
Actually each wcf service method can takes string arguments(xml serialization) and return data as string(xml serialization).From the client application(windows app or asp.net app) send data(list of objects) with xml serialization to wcf service method then service method do implement logic, after that it again de-serialization data(list to xml string )and send back to client application. you told about manageable chunks on the server side(wcf service side)..how it can be implements..? Thanks..

Comment: You should not be doing any serialization in your code. It should be handled automatically. I have updated my answer with the code to do this. Please try it out first and see if it stops the error.:)

Comment: I wil trying to implement.. :)